# convert a roman number to int in cpp using unordered map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I was trying to convert a roman number to int in cpp using unordered map just to avoid if else or switch. You can say I was trying to implement what I leant in a question.
I wrote this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int romanToInt(string s) 
{
    int result=0;
    unordered_map <string, int> roman;
    roman["I"] = 1;
    roman["V"] = 5;
    roman["X"] = 10;
    roman["L"] = 50;
    roman["C"] = 100;
    roman["D"] = 500;
    roman["M"] = 1000;
    for( int i=0; i < s.length(); i++ )
     {
        result += roman[s[i]];
     }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    cout << romanToInt("XIII");
}
```

it doesn't work and I dont get whats wrong. I tried cout << roman["X"] and it gives the output 10 but when i pass s[i] or even s[1] as roman's argument it doesn't work. Please help as I dont understand the compiler's error message and have no idea how to solve it in my own.

The compiler's error:

```
  983 |       operator[](key_type&& __k)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
d:\appdata\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\unordered_map.h:983:29: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type' {aka 'char'} to 'std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::key_type&&' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&&'}
  983 |       operator[](key_type&& __k)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Comment: `s[i]` is a __`char`__, not a `std::string`.

Comment: `no known conversion from 'char' to 'std::string'` is the error message.  You are using a `char` where a `std::string` is expected.

Comment: That's not how Roman Numerals work.

Comment: Here's a challenge:  XCVIII (98 decimal).  Yeah, try numbers with the digits 4 or 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of indexing a `std::string` is `char`. Your `map` is keyed by `std::string`. When you try to do `roman[s[i]];`, it tries to look up a `char` in a `std::string`-keyed mapping, which doesn't work (no implicit conversion is defined for `char` to `std::string`). Easiest fix is to change the `map` to be keyed by `char` here:

```
unordered_map<char, int> roman;  // Change string to chat
roman['I'] = 1;   // Change double-quotes to single-quotes so you're using char
roman['V'] = 5;   // Do it for all of them
// ...
roman['M'] = 1000;
```

You could also shorten and optimize the code a bit by constructing the `unordered_map` directly, and making it `static` so it's not rebuilt on every call, replacing all the code above with just:

```
static unordered_map<char, int> roman{{'I',1},{'V',5},{'X',10},{'L',50},{'C',100},{'D',500},{'M',1000}};
```